# Can divergence be thought of as a Radon-Nikodym derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, radon-nikodym

The divergence theorem states roughly

$$\int_\Omega \operatorname{div}U\ dV=\int_{\partial \Omega}U\cdot n\ dS$$

where $U$ is a vector field, $\Omega$ is a region of space with a smooth boundary, $n$ is a smooth normal vector field on its boundary.

This looks alot like a Radon-Nikodym derivative: a certain function on sets can be obtained by integrating something on that set. In this interpretation, we would think of the right hand side of the equation, the flux of $U$ out of $\Omega$, as a (signed) measure. It seems like it should be additive like a measure should be, and perhaps it can even be extended to the Borel sigma algebra via something like Carathéodory's extension theorem.

The other question is if this "flux measure" is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. This is plausible since the flux out of a flat surface should be zero: remember that we're thinking of closed surfaces here, so we should be integrating on "both sides" of the flat surface, which will cancel out.

Can this interpretation in any way be made rigorous?

Comment: I'm not really seeing the analogy since the integrals are over different spaces. A Radon-Nikodym derivative lets you write one measure as an integral over another, but the sets are the same on both sides. I suppose one way to fix that is to rewrite both integrals as being over some set which compactly contains $\Omega$ but then you start needing distribution theory to do it...

Comment: @Ian The right hand side is a function $\mu(\Omega)$ of the set $\Omega$, which I'm saying can be thought of as a kind of measure. The left hand side is an integral over $\Omega$ with respect to some preexisting measure $\lambda$.

Comment: In that respect sure, the divergence is formally $d\mu/d\lambda$. But I don't think $\mu$ is actually a signed measure. For one thing, with countable operations you can leave the smooth boundary domains altogether...

Comment: @Ian Really the boundary just needs to be piecewise smooth, and I think the piecewise smooth boundary sets form a ring of sets which generates the Borel sigma algebra, so I think we should be able to extend $\mu$ to an actual measure with Carathéodory.

Comment: If you are interested in this type of question the direction you should go is toward geometric measure theory.